# postgres point insert

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4, functions

I have a table with a point data type that stores the latitude and longitude.  I plan to insert from a function, and the input argument is defined as a `float(18)` [which is where I suspect the problem comes from].

Let's say the following values are used:

```
48.277274, -116.5547745
```

If I insert these with from the command line the database shows those values.  But if I insert them from the function the values in the database are:

```
48.2772750854492, -116.55477142334
```

I'm not doing anything to modify the values, as I mention above I believe bringing them in as float is causing the problem, but I've tried various other types and only get other issues.

Would greatly appreciate any help.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION myfun(
    float(18), --   lat
    float(18)) --  lon
  RETURNS integer AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    postcnt integer; 
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO user(usergeo)
   VALUES (point($1,$2))
   RETURN 1;
END
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
```

Comment: http://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: What's wrong with `numeric`?

Comment: [Documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-geometric.html#AEN6923) says point function takes  floating-point numbers as arguments

Answer (score 1):

When executing this:

```
INSERT INTO table VALUES(point(48.277274, -116.5547745));
```

the two decimal constants are implicitly casted to double precision numbers,
since it corresponds to the closest matching types for the `point()` function:

```
test=> \df point
                                  List of functions
   Schema   | Name  | Result data type |        Argument data types         |  Type  
------------+-------+------------------+------------------------------------+--------
 pg_catalog | point | point            | box                                | normal
 pg_catalog | point | point            | circle                             | normal
 pg_catalog | point | point            | double precision, double precision | normal
 pg_catalog | point | point            | lseg                               | normal
 pg_catalog | point | point            | path                               | normal
 pg_catalog | point | point            | polygon                            | normal
(6 rows)
```

On the other hand, when executing this:

```
SELECT myfun(48.277274, -116.5547745)
```

the two decimal constants are implicitly casted to `real` as the type,
because float(n) is equivalent to real when 1<=n<=24, as explained in the
[documentation on datatypes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html):

> PostgreSQL also supports the SQL-standard notations float and 
>   float(p) for specifying inexact numeric types. Here, p specifies the 
>   minimum acceptable precision in binary digits. PostgreSQL accepts 
>   float(1) to float(24) as selecting the real type, while float(25) to 
>   float(53) select double precision. Values of p outside the allowed 
>   range draw an error. float with no precision specified is taken to 
>   mean double precision

This downcast comes with a loss of precision, because, from the same doc page:

> On most platforms, the real type has a range of at least 1E-37 to
>   1E+37 with a precision of at least 6 decimal digits. The double
>   precision type typically has a range of around 1E-307 to 1E+308 with a
>   precision of at least 15 digits

Conclusion: use `double precision` instead of `float(18)`, which in fact is a synonym for the less-precise `real`.